# gvim, latex suite, and okular forward search issue

Tags: ubuntu, vim, gvim, latex, okular

I have a gotten my gvim + vim-latexsuite + okular working well, except for one thing:  forward search.  I have tried many of the hints on line, but I can't find the solution, but I am close!

So, I have the standard setup that \ll latex a doc, \lv opens it, and \ls is supposed to do forward search.  \ls *almost* works.  it jumps to the correct page, but it does not highlight the relevant text in a red box like gvim + evince.  Somewhat annoying because then I do have to search in the page for the right spot.  Is anyone else having this problem?

I am on kubuntu 18.04, if that information helps.